# up arrow randomly stops working in x2go

Tags: keyboard, remote-desktop

I have been using x2go for a while. I'm running ubuntu on client and server. On occasion, the up arrow just stops working on the remote desktop, even though it is still working on the client.  I'm completely puzzled by this.

Here is the xev output for left, right, down, up:

left:

```
KeyRelease event, serial 36, synthetic NO, window 0x3600001,
    root 0xb7, subw 0x0, time 3738756369, (-172,430), root:(699,925),
    state 0x0, keycode 113 (keysym 0xff51, Left), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

right:

```
KeyPress event, serial 36, synthetic NO, window 0x3600001,
    root 0xb7, subw 0x0, time 3738757962, (-172,430), root:(699,925),
    state 0x0, keycode 114 (keysym 0xff53, Right), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
XFilterEvent returns: False
```

down:

```
KeyPress event, serial 36, synthetic NO, window 0x3600001,
    root 0xb7, subw 0x0, time 3738758877, (-172,430), root:(699,925),
    state 0x0, keycode 116 (keysym 0xff54, Down), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

up:

```
FocusOut event, serial 36, synthetic NO, window 0x3600001,
    mode NotifyGrab, detail NotifyAncestor

FocusIn event, serial 36, synthetic NO, window 0x3600001,
    mode NotifyUngrab, detail NotifyAncestor

KeymapNotify event, serial 36, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  4294967223 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
           0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

Any ideas??? Thank you.

Comment: Is your problem the same as [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/582552/x2go-arrow-key-is-not-working-properly)? Another related workaround is [here](https://bugs.x2go.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=1339).

Comment: Perhaps the Up key is being registered for something locally and its not being passed through? unless those traces for Up appear exactly when the Up key is pressed (indicating that the Up key is actually sent to the remote client, but the client does not register it correctly)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same exact issue where the up arrow is giving something like this at the x2go session, but it is working perfectly fine on my client.

```
KeymapNotify event, serial 36, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  4294967223 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
           0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

It went away after doing a computer restart. Guess the answer to this one might really be "Have you tried turning it off and on again?!"

Wouldn't hurt to try.